# Should I execute inserts in database migration?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, migration

I have tables **"course"**, **"tab"** and **"courses_tabs**". The last one contains tabs that should be displayed in the courses.
I've generated migrations for db structure of these tables and now I need to fill in **"courses_tabs"** adding all tabs for each course.

I wonder which way is right for that task:
**Should I create Doctrine2 migration with INSERTs and foreach loop (docrine2 doesn't allow to run queries to get list of ids) or create command and run it manually and only once?**

Comment: The idea is to get your database from the last version to the actual one. If this involves adding all tabs to all courses, than yes. If you only want to do this in your development/staging environment to test something, then it doesn't belong in the migration scripts.

Comment: Tabs were previously static and now admins should be able to disable some of them. So if I don't fill the **"courses_tabs"**, users won't see tabs until admins turn them on. In this case I need to populate this table in production database.

Comment: Then this belongs in your migration scripts.

Comment: I've implemented that as migration. It seems to be a right solution, thanks!